# How can I install ASP.NET MVC 1 on a new Windows Server 2008 R2 server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, asp.net-mvc, web-platform-installer

I have a new Windows Server 2008 R2 box that is successfully running several applications built for ASP.NET MVC 2.

I now am trying to run an older application that was build for ASP.NET MVC 1.

The Microsoft Web Platform Installer has **no entry** for ASP.NET MVC 1.

What's the recommended way to install **older versions** of ASP.NET MVC?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, nevermind, found it.

The MVC1 download is no longer available through web-platform installer, but it *is available*, at the time of this writing, on microsoft.com:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=53289097-73ce-43bf-b6a6-35e00103cb4b&displaylang=en